# Third littler example/littler script --how do you run it?

Tags: r, bash, littler

So, I'm trying to reproduce the example [here](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/blob/master/ANNOUNCEMENT)

So the first three examples:

```
echo 'cat(pi^2,"\n")' | r
```

and

```
r -e 'cat(pi^2, "\n")'
```

and

```
ls -l /boot | awk '!/^total/ {print $5}' | \
             r -e 'fsizes <- as.integer(readLines());
                print(summary(fsizes)); stem(fsizes)'
```

work great. The third one:

```
$ cat examples/fsizes.r
        #!/usr/bin/env r

        fsizes <- as.integer(readLines())
        print(summary(fsizes))
        stem(fsizes)
```

How do you run this? Sorry for the dumb question I am no bash guru...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is in `examples/fsizes.r`, then make it executable:

```
chmod +x examples/fsizes.r
```

And then run it with:

```
./examples/fsizes.r
```

The script expects input, one integer per line. When you run it, you can enter line by line, and press control-d to end the input. Or, you can create a file with numbers, and use input redirection, for example:

```
./examples/fsizes.r < input.txt
```

Comment: But *how* do you make them work? Do you copy that script somewhere? How do you launch it? For example, for that script, what are the incantations?

Comment: But this is not an R script, it is a littler script. Is it the same?

Comment: Littler can do things rscript can't which is why I'm trying to learn to use it. But this is beside the point. So does it mean I have to substitute the shebang  at the top of your script by the one they use?

Comment: Ok. It launches now, but it does nothing~ Have you been able to get it to do anything?

Comment: The script expects input, one integer per line. When you run it, you can enter line by line, and press control d to end the input. Or, you can create a file with numbers, and use input redirection. Does this answer your question, or did you mean something else?

Comment: It's perfect now! Thanks! (I'm starting from a very low base)

Comment: @user189035 You **quote** the example for launching it:  `ls -l /boot | awk '!/^total/ {print $5}'` produces output which the script then consumes.  This obviously assumes you have a directory `/boot` as most Linux systems would.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: yes, thanks for the help here and at the other question. As I said, I'm really starting from a low base. I am not a programmer  and my package is, as you put it, taken hostage by a CRAN bug report which I don't understand. Trying to fix those leaks with very little knowledge and in high seas!